# Spring Security forgets authentication with custom login form

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, spring-security

I followed more or less this description to create a custom login form:
http://technology-for-human.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-2-with-spring-3-protection-with.html

The login form uses a LoginBean, and the LoginBean uses an AuthenticationService:

```
@Service("authenticationService")
public class AuthenticationService {
    @Resource(name = "authenticationManager")
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public boolean login(String username, String password) {
        try {
            Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
            if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
                return true;
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        }
    return false;
    }
}
```

Generally everything works as expected, the login methods return true for my user. But then the login-form appears again and I can see that `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns null.

The Spring config looks like this:

```
<security:http auto-config='true'>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsf" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsf" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Any ideas what probably could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think the security context is not persisted back to the session.  Do you have the springSecurityFilterChain configured as a filter in the web.xml?

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly as you have posted. How can I debug whether the context is persited or not?

Comment: You can enable the info logging for spring security, that might give you some clues.  You could also add another filter of your own which prints the contents of the httpsession. Just to be sure - check if you have cookies enabled in the browser you are trying this from.